# How unit test on Code Contract should look like?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-contracts

I have this method in `ContractClass`:

```
  public UserModel GetUser(string groupName, string login) {
     Contract.Requires(groupName != null);
     Contract.Requires(groupName != string.Empty);
     Contract.Requires(login != null);
     Contract.Requires(login != string.Empty);

     return default(UserModel);
  }
```

How would you test this? Do you test all combinations of all possible scenarios when contract fails (ex: `groupName` is empty and `login` is null ... and so on)?

Comment: `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(value)` or `String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)`

Comment: Aren't contracts removed from release build? Do you run your tests against non-release build?

Comment: If you mean all possible permutations, I fail to see the point in that. After all, the checks on each parameters are independent of each other here. It would quickly become unmanageable if you add more parameters too.

Comment: Since I am not a C# devel, to me it would seem that the best option would be to mock the `Requires()` method, because to write a proper unit test, you have to isolate said unit. Then again, this entire method looks like made of pure global state.

Comment: @zerkms Yes they are removed but i am runing tests while being still in `Debug` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, otherwise

- you have not tested all possible faults,
- and you have dependencies in your tests.

E.g.: If you only test that it fails when `groupName` is equal to `null` and `login` is equal to `null`, and your test fails - you can not be sure that it fails for the correct condition. And what's even more important: You can not even be sure that you have all the correct and important calls to `Contract.Requires`.

Comment: `You can not even be sure that you have all the correct and important requires.` how would you be so sure about this? All you can do, at this point, is `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. A failing precondition is a sign of a bug in **calling** side. When you fail your preconditions in unit tests, you basically have shown, that there is a bug (intended) in your tests. Note that, Design by Contract is different from defensive coding.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't write any unit tests for those Code Contracts at all. If your preconditions are wrong, then peer code review is a better way of picking that up. If your preconditions are correct, then all you'll end up testing is that the Code Contract engine works, not that *your* code works.

It might be worth running integration tests to check that your preconditions are not too strict, but in most cases the output of the static verifier will be a better guide.

If a precondition becomes particularly complex, then there's an argument for unit testing it. However, in that instance, I'd be tempted to extract the precondition into a `[Pure]` method, and unit test *that* instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, almost always my precondition are quite simple so maybe I would be better off without them.